# Thompson's Construction Algorithm and RE to NFA

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, nfa

I am attempting to make a method which will take a string (a valid regular expression) and output a corresponding nondeterministic finite automata. From the research I've done, it looks like [Thompson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction_algorithm) is the most applicable here since I will only be handling the kleene star, union, and parenthesis symbols and the language will only be {a, b, e} with e representing empty transition.

Also, a big problem I am having is figuring out how to handle nested parenthesis in the regular expressions. Input here would be appreciated.

My question is about the best/most straight-forward way to represent this in code. I will need to distinguish each node from one another and keep track of the transitions coming out of the node and where those transitions lead. I have looked into using a Digraph, however it appears as if you can only represent a node and where the node can lead to, leaving out the transition that get you to that new node. Any suggestions for an architecture here would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In this repository, you can find a Java implementation of Thompson's construction:
https://github.com/meghdadFar/regex

Comment: First, an NFA is being created from the regex, then an input string is being matched against that NFA.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but I implemented this in Python for [my monograph](https://github.com/juanplopes/pyrex/blob/master/pyrex.py). Sadly, the text is in portuguese, but the implementation is very simple.

In fact, it compiles the expression as a sequence of non-deterministic instructions for a hypothetical machine. For example, the expression a(b|c)+d would be compiled as:

```
 0000: CONSUME a
 0001: JUMP (1, 3)
 0002: CONSUME b
 0003: JUMP (2,)
 0004: CONSUME c
 0005: JUMP (1, -4)
 0006: CONSUME d
 0007: MATCH!
```

There are only three types of instructions (and `MATCH` only appears at the end).

- `CONSUME x` consumes the next char of the input if it is `x`
- `JUMP (a, [b])` jumps relatively to all labels defined non-determinstically
- `MATCH!` self-describing